# Resolving promise doesn't show data in template

Tags: javascript, ember.js, htmlbars

I have tried several versions/attempts to create and return a `RSVP.Promise` as a param to my template.

All the console.log give reasonable values, so the promises *are* resolving.
The **problem** I have (which is then also the **question**) is how to return that resolving values to my template.

Here are the versions I've tried:

```
// in controller.js
testA: Ember.computed('sessionAccount.account.id', function() {
    let _this = this;
    let promise = new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        _this.get('store').findAll('accounts2workgroup').then(function(a2ws) {
            let workgroups = [];
            a2ws.forEach(function(a2w){
                if(a2w.get('rights')>1) {
                    workgroups.push(a2w.get('workgroup'));
                }
            });
            console.log(workgroups);
            _this.set('wgAsAdmin', workgroups); // this works
            resolve(Ember.A(workgroups));  //=> [Object] in rendered template
            // return workgroups; // no, not that way
        });
    });

    promise.then(function(data) {
        console.log('did resolve');
        console.log(data);
    })

    return promise; 
}).property('sessionAccount.account.id'),

testB: Ember.computed('sessionAccount.account.id', function() {
    return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    let workgroups = Ember.ArrayProxy.create([{'label': 'TestB Label'}]);
        resolve(workgroups);

    });
}),

testC: Ember.computed(function() {
    return this.store.findAll('artists2workgroup').then(function(a2ws) {
            let workgroups = [];
            a2ws.forEach(function(a2w){
                if(a2w.get('rights')>1) {
                    workgroups.push(a2w.get('workgroup'));
                }
            });
            console.log(workgroups);
            return workgroups; //=> [Object] in rendered
    });
}),

testD: Ember.computed(function() {
    return this.store.findAll('workgroup'); // this of course works, but that's not what I want...
}),
```

in my template I test all my tests like so:

```
<h4>TestB</h4>
{{#each testB as |wg|}}
        {{wg}}<br>
        {{wg.label}}<br>
{{/each}}
testB: {{testB}}<br>
testB.length: {{testB.length}}<br>
```

and all (but the last testD obviously) render to

> **TestB**
>   testB: [object Object]
>   testB.length:

though I would expect/want them to show

> TestB
>   <DS.PromiseObject:ember1117>
>   BB-Promotion
>   testB: <DS.PromiseObject:ember1117>
>   testB.length: 1

I know there are ways around that (I can set another property when resolving f.e.), but want to do it the right way and learn how to do this.
And I know, that these examples don't make too much sense. That's just the basic functionality, it will be enhanced once I get this running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First please avoid the [explicit promise construction antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it)! Also you don't have to save `this`, because you have arrow functions in `ember-cli`. So lets rewrite your `testA`:

```
testA: Ember.computed('sessionAccount.account.id', function() {
    return this.get('store').findAll('accounts2workgroup').then(a2ws => {
        return workgroups
            .filter(a2w => a2w.get('rights') > 1)
            .map(a2w => a2w.get('workgroup'))
    });
}).property('sessionAccount.account.id'),
```

Now this won't make it work. The problem here is that ember templates are not promise-aware. So you have three options:

1. Just don't do this. Often you can use the routes `model` hook to do async work.
2. Use something like `ember-promise-helpers` from the template.
3. Don't just return a Promise.

If you can't do 1, I recommend to go with 3. For this you need to understand the [`PromiseProxyMixin`](https://emberjs.com/api/ember/2.15/classes/Ember.PromiseProxyMixin). In `ember-data` you have two implementations for this Mixin, the [`PromiseArray`](https://emberjs.com/api/ember-data/2.14/classes/DS.PromiseArray) and [`PromiseObject`](https://emberjs.com/api/ember-data/2.14/classes/DS.PromiseObject)

All `ember-data` methods like `findAll`, `findRecord`, `query` or async relationships return a `PromiseObject`/`PromiseArray`. So they are both, `promise` **and** regular object. The `promise` part is useful in the routes `model` hook, and the `Object`/`Array` part is useful for computed properties. So the easiest way to go for you, is to split your CP into two:

```
allWorkgroups: Ember.computed(function() {
    return this.get('store').findAll('accounts2workgroup');
}),
testA: Ember.computed('sessionAccount.account.id', 'allWorkgroups.@each.rights', 'allWorkgroups.@each.workgroup', function() {
    return this.get('allWorkgroups')
        .filter(a2w => a2w.get('rights') > 1)
        .map(a2w => a2w.get('workgroup'))
}).property('sessionAccount.account.id'),
```

This will work, because first `allWorkgroups` will be an empty array/unresolved promise, but then when the promise resolves the array gets updated, and the `testA` CP will recompute.

However you can also manually create a new `PromiseArray`:

```
testA: Ember.computed('sessionAccount.account.id', 'allWorkgroups.@each.rights', 'allWorkgroups.@each.workgroup', function() {
    const promise = this.get('store').findAll('accounts2workgroup').then(a2ws => {
        return workgroups
            .filter(a2w => a2w.get('rights') > 1)
            .map(a2w => a2w.get('workgroup'))
    });

    return DS.PromiseArray.create({promise});
}).property('sessionAccount.account.id'),
```

However you should know, that in both cases you won't get any information if the Promise fails!

Comment: Thanks a lot for this comprehensive answer! I've learned a lot! (most strikingle the fact, that templetes aren't promise aware)